# How to change input search bar to auto complete search?

Tags: angular, search, ionic4

I am working on ionic 4 project. My project is getting data `json` from url using input search and button for execute. My code working fine without problem, but I want change the input search bar to auto complete search for more easier. I tried different codes, but no one working!

***My code:***

```
export class FlightsearchPage {
      public search = ''
      public flight : any
      constructor(private http: HTTP, public loadingController: LoadingController) {

      }

      async addThemFunction(){
        this.http.get('/search/web/find?query='+this.search+'', {}, {})
        .then(data => {
          const parsed = JSON.parse(data.data);
          this.flight = parsed.results;
        }), err=>{}
      }
}
```

***HTML:***

```
<ion-content padding>
    <ion-input   [(ngModel)]="search"></ion-input>
    <ion-button color="primary" (click)="addThemFunction()">Search</ion-button>
{{flight}}

<ion-item *ngFor="let item of flight" > 
  {{item.id}}
  </ion-item>
</ion-content>
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `keyup` which will help you monitor on the field change.

```
<ion-content padding>
    <ion-input   [(ngModel)]="search" (keyup)="keyPressed($event)" ></ion-input>
    <ion-button color="primary" (click)="addThemFunction(search)">Search</ion-button>
{{flight}}

<ion-item *ngFor="let item of flight" > 
  {{item.id}}
  </ion-item>
</ion-content>
```

in TS:

```
keyPressed(event: any) { // without type info
    console.log(event.target.value); // get you the typed value;
this.addThemFunction(event.target.value);
  }

 async addThemFunction(search){

    this.http.get('/search/web/find?query='+search+'', {}, {})
    .then(data => {

      const parsed = JSON.parse(data.data);
      this.flight = parsed.results;
    }), err=>{
    }
  }
```

I think this should work.